# Problems converting Array of objects to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created an object which contains all the results from a query ran against the database.  these results are then stored in an Array.

I am trying to convert this array into an ArrayList so that it can be used to import into a document.

I have tried:

```
//trustSummary is the name of my array
ArrayList data = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(trustSummary));
```

But this appears to be causing issues (`ClassCastException`) when I am trying to run the below code in another part of the application. Would anyone please be able to point in the correct direction to resolve this issue.

```
for (Iterator rows = data.iterator(); rows.hasNext();)
   ArrayList row = (ArrayList) rows.next();
```

Comment: `data` is the `ArrayList`. Not its elements.

Comment: what is the type of `trustSummary` ?

Comment: I think you have here an ArrayList containing an array of objects (each array of objects is a row of the result). Try casting to Object[] in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `ArrayList(Collection)` constructor you are using here in the part where you write `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(trustSummary));` creates an `ArrayList` with the elements from the source collection, it does not create an `ArrayList` with another collection as element.

So you need either to fix that line, or change the line

```
ArrayList row = (ArrayList) rows.next();
```

to

```
TrustSummary ts = (TrustSummary) rows.next();
```

Generally I would advise using generics, to avoid that sort of confusion regarding a collection's types.

In your case that would either be for example

```
List<TrustSummary> summaries = new ArrayList<TrustSummary>(Arrays.asList(trustSummary));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would only work if `trustSummary` is:

```
ArrayList[] trustSummary;
```

or: (though this doesn't really make sense, because then the array would only have 1 element, thus you may as well work with the element directly)

```
ArrayList trustSummary;
```

Both of the above works because `Arrays.asList` takes either an array or a bunch of items you want in the array as parameters.

The reason trustSummary needs to be defined as above (with `ArrayList` being the elements) is because the iterator grabs the elements one at a time from `data` (which was converted from the array) (so the return type of `next()` is the type used in the array (`ArrayList` in this case)).

This would work:

```
String[] trustSummary = {"1", "2", "3"};
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(trustSummary));
for (Iterator rows = data.iterator(); rows.hasNext();)
  System.out.println((String)rows.next());
```

Or this:

```
String trustSummary = "1";
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(trustSummary));
for (Iterator rows = data.iterator(); rows.hasNext();)
  System.out.println((String)rows.next());
```

Replace `String` with the desired type and change appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (Iterator rows = data.iterator(); rows.hasNext();) 
{
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) rows.next();
    ArrayList row = (ArrayList) entry.getValue(); 
}
```

Comment: Where do you find `Map` in the question?